# Cognito Facebook graph api user data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I am wondering whether if I continue with cognito Facebook login whether I will still be able to get the data like age, gender and interests like i believe you can with normal Facebook login.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from OP: You can do this easily.

In the facebooksigninprovider class of Cognito it is just calling the standard loginWithReadPermissions method from the Facebook SDK. So all you have to do is add permissions to the array.

Example below I added get the users email to the signin:

```
  LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(signInActivity,
                Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Not through Cognito, you can't. Cognito only leverages Facebook to validate a user's identity, after that there's no integration.

I would think it should still be possible, though, with a little code that branches off of the login callback that Cognito uses. Again, though, this won't be through any Cognito feature and would need to be on your end.